# Code produces unexpected output when extra output statement added

Tags: c++

So I'm testing out certain arguments for an assignment, which is basically encrypt a text file using a provided cipher. Here's the code, which is not working as I expect:

```
int main()
{
fstream file("text.txt",ios::out, ios::trunc);
ifstream key("key.txt");
char box[16][2];
string input;
getline(cin, input);
file << input;

for (int row = 0; row < 16; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 2; col++)
    {
        key >> box[row][col];

    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 16; row++)
    {
        if (input.at(i) != box[row][0])
        {
            cout << input.at(i);
        }
        else if (input.at(i) == box[row][0])
        {
            input.at(i) = box[row][1];
            cout << input.at(i);
        }
    }
}

file.close();
key.close();

system("pause");
}
```

But if I replace the `i` loop by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < 16; row++)
    {
        if (input.at(i) == box[row][0])
        {
            input.at(i) = box[row][1];
            cout << input.at(i);
        }
    }
}
```

It works just fine with the exception that it doesn't read anything that isn't in the cipher file. This includes whitespaces and everything. So I thought, alright let's just add some code that does something when my previous conditions are not met. Well... that [produces unexpected output.](https://i.gyazo.com/1eb258f98316eb1874fa73155d8c30ab.png). Just for reference, [here is the output of the original code](https://i.gyazo.com/10e2c19154e93147c4dc2315752783ea.png)  with the same word used.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clearly show the code that is *not* working?  I don't know what you are talking about with "second argument" .

Comment: the "here is the incorrect loop" looks the same as part of your first block of code?

Comment: @M.M Yes, the first block is the current incorrect solution. The second block I shared is what gives me the result from the second link I shared. The second argument is the new "if" statement I added.

Comment: Your code seems to do exactly what it says. Maybe you meant to only print `cout << input.at(i);` in the case that the letter was not found at all in the entire row?

Comment: It'd help if you posted the contents of the key file, and your complete program. (There are some lines missing before the `main()` line).  Also `fstream file("text.txt",ios::out, ios::trunc);` is illegal , the second `,` should be a `|`. Did your compiler really accept that?

Comment: @M.M yes, I'm trying to print out `input.at(i)` if a certain letter isn't found. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The key file is currently 2 columns of 16 rows. The letter on the left row, and the equivalent character to convert to on the right row.

Also, I guess my compiler must be generous. I'll fix it.

Comment: The `row` loop executes 16 times and you are doing `cout << input.at(i)` for every one of those 16 executions. So the total amount of output is 16 times as many characters as the input.

Comment: @M.M Ah alright. I just put the cout outside the second for loop. It seemed to have fixed that... Of course it was that simple >.> Thank you. Although one problem is that in a new program it isn't recognizing new lines in the text file it's encrypting to.

Answer (score 0):

With the revised logic, you are printing each character 16 times. If the cypher for it can be found, you are still printing it 15 more times.

Comment: What I dont understand is it's all in the same for loop. When I remove the if statement if(x!=y), it doesn't repeat 16 times, but only when I ask it to check if something isn't there.